# Copying data from multiple excel files to specified columns using python

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to create a script which would run through excel files in a folder and copy the contents to a workbook. The aim is to copy the contents of each file onto different columns where the spacing between the columns is a set difference, ie. columns: A, D(A+3) & G(D+3). For my example I am running my code with 3 base datasets.

When I run the code, the final dataset ends up copying across the final excel document 3 times across the specified columns, instead of copying the 3 unique documents to the specified columns.

```
What I want: A B C
What I get: C C C
```

Code:

```
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import string     

for file in os.listdir(file_path):
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        print(f'Loading file {file}...')
        wb = load_workbook(file_path+file)
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]
        wb1 = load_workbook(new_path+'data.xlsx')
        ws1 = wb1.active
        #calculate max rows and columns in source dataset
        mr = ws.max_row
        mc = ws.max_column
        m = [0,3,6]
        #copying data to new sheet
        for i in range(1,mr+1):
            for j in range(1,mc+1):
                for y in range(0,3):
                    #reading cell value from source
                    c = ws.cell(row = i, column = j)
                    #writing read value to destination
                    ws1.cell(row = i, column = j+int(m[y])).value = c.value
        wb1.save(new_path+'data.xlsx')
```

Thank you for your help.

Edit:

The data is all in the same format and looks like:https://ibb.co/TMStH9j Current output: https://ibb.co/dmcbSJ1 Desired output: https://ibb.co/C1nqKJv

Comment: If understand correctly you're running exactly the same code for each `if file.endswith('.xlsx'):` block - if so, then it's no surprise that you end up with the content of the last file?

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need the `int()` here: `int(m[y])`.

Comment: The 'if file.endswith('.xlsx'):' is there to ensure that only .xlsx files will copied from my understanding. The 'for loop' before iterates through each file in the folder so does this not mean the contents copied across should be different?

Comment: I know why you use the `if`-block, but that wasn't my point. My point was: You do 3 times exactly the same, including the writing to `new_path+'data.xlsx'`. Why shouldn't the 2 time not override the first, and the last time not override the 2. - what is the mechanism preventing it?

Comment: Ah okay, I get what you mean now @Timus, still getting my head around all the indents so thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the creation and saving of the new workbook out of the for loop so that it is not overwritten each time a new file is looped over.

Also you need a way to count how many files you have looped over, so that you can increment the columns where the new data is copied to in the new workbook. Please see  below:

**Edit**:

To get your expected output, I also removed the inner-most for loop and m list to rather use a single variable to space the columns of each new excel data apart.

```
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import string

# Create new workbook outside of for loop so that it is not overwritten each loop
wb1 = Workbook()
ws1 = wb1.active

# count variable so each loop increments the column where the data is posted
count = 0

# how many columns to space data apart
col_spacing = 2

for file in os.listdir(file_path):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        print(f"Loading file {file}...")
        wb = load_workbook(file_path + file)
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]
        # calculate max rows and columns in source dataset
        mr = ws.max_row
        mc = ws.max_column
        
        # copying data to new sheet
        for i in range(1, mr + 1):
            for j in range(1, mc + 1):
                # reading cell value from source
                c = ws.cell(row=i, column=j)
                # writing read value to destination
                ws1.cell(row=i, column=count + j + (count * col_spacing)).value = c.value
        # increment column count
        count += 1
# save new workbook after all files have been looped through
wb1.save(new_path + "data.xlsx")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same final dataset: C C C, with this.

Comment: In your original question, can you please include some examples of what the data looks like in each excel file, as well as a complete example of the expected output? I think the issue is in how the data is being looped over.

Comment: I have edited my answer to work for your use case and it's working for me, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: You could first collect all `.xlsx`-files from `os.listdir(file_path)` in a list, then determine `col_spacing`, and then process the files in the list?

Comment: @Timus good idea, but I was trying to keep it as per the question's aim: "The aim is to copy the contents of each file onto different columns where the spacing between the columns is a set difference". I might have misinterpreted this. I agree that your suggested method would be better.

Comment: @Timus, If you wouldn't mind, could you post your interpretation and solution as a separate answer? Would love to see how I could have structured my code better

Comment: @rhynohorn The solution from keipala is fine. My comment was based on a misunderstanding of the purpose of `col_spacing` (I thought you wanted a grouping of corresponding columns). One thing I'd change: I'd use `Path` from `pathlib` instead of `os`: `for file in Path(file_path).glob(*.xlsx): ...`. So you get the files directly and also don't have to rebuild the the paths.